# Как выводить все элементы из Бд?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

У меня в бд есть колонка TEXT, в которой хранится словарь. Вопрос такой - как вытащить оттуда все элементы?

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (
    id INT,
    cards TEXT,
    wins INT,
    defeat INT,
    duel TEXT
)""")
con.commit()
...
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO info (id, cards, wins, defeat, duel) VALUES ({member.id}, '[]', 0, 0, Null)""")
...
test = cur.execute(f"""SELECT cards FROM info WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}""").fetchone()[0]
print(test) #["", "", ""]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует сначала выполнить запрос

```
test = cur.execute(f"""SELECT cards FROM info WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}""")
```

затем уже работать с данными

```
print(test.fetchone()[0])
```

В качестве примера:

```
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO info (id, cards, wins, defeat, duel) \
    VALUES (1, '["test1", "Тест"]', 0, 0, Null)""")
test = cur.execute(f"""SELECT cards FROM info WHERE id = 1""")
print(test.fetchone()[0])
```

> ["test1", "Тест"]

Данные, полученные с помощью `fetchone()[0]`, будут иметь тип данных `str`, поэтому для удобства работы с ними их можно привести к соответствующему виду с помощью библиотеки [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

```
print(type(test.fetchone()[0]))
>> <class 'str'>

data = ast.literal_eval(test.fetchone()[0]))
print(type(data), data)
>> <class 'list'> ['test1', 'Тест']
```

Теперь с данными можно работать как с обычным списком.

Comment: В таком случае выводится тоже самое. Предположим - есть два элемента `["test1", "Тест"]`. Как мне их достать?

Comment: @FiolDoll, дополнил ответ

Comment: Простите, не точно выразился. Мне нужно получить их без ковычек и скобок

Comment: @FiolDoll, дополнил ответ снова

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно просто.

```
   for test in cursor.execute(f"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}"):
```

1. Вместо "test" можно вписать что угодно.
2. SELECT ... - получаем необходимые категории из таблицы.
3. FROM ... - название таблицы.

Предположим мы хотим вывести имя и айди пользователя.

```
   for test in cursor.execute(f"SELECT name, id FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}"):
```

Далее по нумерации вытаскиваем из таблицы значения. Нумерация в таблице начинается с 0.
И так:

```
    print(f"Получено сообщение от пользователя {test[0]}. ID: {test[1]}")
```